# SQL - Update fierld with MAX date from another table

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-update

I am using SQL server and wish to update a `Suppliers` table with with the date of the most recent invoice from that supplier, held within the `invoices` table.

I Have tried:

```
UPDATE Suppliers
SET Last_Billed_Date = (SELECT MAX(invoice_date) as 'MAXDATE'
                        FROM Invoices i
                        INNER JOIN Suppliers s
                            ON i.supplierID=s.id
                       )
```

But this simply returned the `MAX` date from the entire `Invoices` table.

Answer (score 1):

You can do what you want using a correlated subquery:

```
UPDATE Suppliers
    SET Last_Billed_Date = (SELECT MAX(i.invoice_date)
                            FROM Invoices i 
                            WHERE i.supplierID = Suppliers.id);
```

There is no need for a `JOIN` in the subquery.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
UPDATE f1
SET f1.Last_Billed_Date = MAX(f2.invoice_date)
FROM Suppliers f1 INNER JOIN Invoices f2 ON f2.supplierID = f1.id
```

Comment: Its a simple exemple to update a table with an other, all web give this answer...

Answer (score 0):

```
UPDATE Suppliers S
SET S.Last_Billed_Date = (SELECT MAX(i.invoice_date)
                        FROM Invoices i 
                        WHERE i.supplierID = S.supplierID );
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, it is better to explain how to solve the problem and provide the code as an example or reference. Code-only answers can be confusing and lack context.

Comment: @RobertColumbia Thank you for your valuable feedback/suggestion. I would definitely follow this practice henceforth.